# Error occurred when verifying security for the message in CRM On-line

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013, query-expressions

I'm moving out some of the code from a plugin to an external web application. The only thing that needs to be added is the authorization. When executing my *QueryExpression* instance from within the plugin, that's not an issue. However, accessing the date from outside is.   :)

I'm not sure where to provide the credentials (user name and password) so the endpoint at my CRM organization lets me in.

I prefer to resolve it in such a way so I can create a web service reference and work towards it directly. So, the (kind of) requirement is not to go *using* and creating proxy.

How can I do that?!

Here's the **very basic** scenario I'd like to effectuate. I've created a web service reference in VS using the wizard (endpoint address is *Organization.svc*).

```
QueryExpression request = new QueryExpression
{
  EntityName = "account",
  ColumnSet = new ColumnSet()
};

OrganizationServiceClient client = new OrganizationServiceClient();
IEnumerable<Entity> response = client.RetrieveMultiple(request).Entities;
int entityCount = response.Count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest no to use Reference but to use SDK assemblies. Recheck following article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx

Also Recheck this article - http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/sample-code-to-connect-office-365-users-to-crm-2011-online/ and http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/sample-code-for-using-iorganizationservice-in-crm-2011/

Comment: Great link. I missed that one. My googling superpowers are weak, apparently. Does that approach work only on early bound basis or can we access the organization on late bound basis as well?

Comment: The only problem with MS code is the large number of helper classes. I want the solution to be as transparent as possible. For instance, it feels like black magic how one creates a reference to the service for organization, when looking at their code base.

Comment: Ok. In this case you should recheck following articles -Not sure what kind of deployment you have - [OnPrem](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/sample-code-for-using-iorganizationservice-in-crm-2011/), [IFD or Online](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/sample-code-to-connect-office-365-users-to-crm-2011-online/)

Comment: On-line. (It's in the title, hihi.)

Comment: Overworked :) Anyway ask in case you will have further questions.

Comment: No problem, mate. Put in the links form the comment in the reply and I'll mark it as answered.